# Android — How to track bandwidth usage by a process?

Tags: android

I can track the overall and per uid (application) bandwidth usage of Android device by `android.net.TrafficStats`.
However a uid can execute more than one binaries to invoke more than one processes.

I want to know if there is any method or way to get per process bandwidth usage, so that I can trace back the binary that starts the connection to the Internet.

Comment: You might have to root the phone. Is that a problem to you?

Comment: I would prefer my app not to request for root. But I'd like to know even if your answer needs root.

Comment: I do not have an answer for you, but I believe this can only be achieved with a rooted phone.

Comment: Then what's the reason why you think so? I have seen various posts mentioning ways to do that in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested on the network trafic done by your aplication you can try [AT&T ARO](https://developer.att.com/developer/legalAgreementPage.jsp?passedItemId=9700312), you will need to register at AT&T (free) but the tool is very good it acounts for the network done by your aplication only, and you can actually see the Packets being sent and received, and get Advices on were you can improve your network usage.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [nethogs](http://www.binarytides.com/monitor-bandwidth-used-by-each-process-on-ubuntu-linux-with-nethogs/) and its [source code](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) for Linux. As Android in built on Linux kernel, I believe that you can implement it in a similar way.

Comment: Hmm... this seems interesting, I will have a look at it.